# TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'toggle' of '(0 , react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.useContext)(...)' as it is undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I am having issue with my toggle context. The error message in the title point at the line of code below in my navbar.

```
const {theme} = useContext(ThemeContext);
> 34 |     const {toggle} = useContext(ToggleContext);
     |           ^
  35 | 
  36 |     return (
  37 |         <>
```

I don't really understand why it comes as undefined as i have replicate the same pattern for the theme context. See below my components.

Navbar.js

```
import Image from "next/image";
import styles from "../../styles/Home.module.scss"
import Logo  from "../../public/Knowledge Memo.svg"
import { useContext } from "react";
import { ThemeContext } from "../contexts/ThemeContext";
import { ToggleContext } from "../contexts/ToggleContext";

const navbarData  = [
    {   id: "1",
        title: "home",
        ref: "#home"
    },
    {   id:"2",
        title: "Skills",
        ref: "#skills"
    },
    {   id:"3",
        title: "The List",
        ref: "#theList"
    },
    {   id: "4",
        title: "Team",
        ref: "#team"
    },
    {   id: "5",
        title: "Contact",
        ref: "#contact"
    },
];

function Navbar() {

    const {theme} = useContext(ThemeContext);
    const {toggle} = useContext(ToggleContext);

    return (
        <>
            <nav className={
                theme === "light" ? 
                "navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark fixed-top": 
                "navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top id= mainNav"}>
                <div className="container d-flex flex justify-content-between">
                    <a className="navbar-brand h-50" href="#page-top">
                    <div className="navbar-brand"> 
                    <Image 
                    src={Logo} 
                    alt="..."                  
                    fill="#fff"
                    objectFit="contain"
                    className="h-50"                    
                    />
                    </div>
                    </a>                    
                    <button 
                    className="navbar-toggler collapsed" 
                    type="button" 
                    data-bs-toggle="collapse" 
                    data-bs-target="#navbarResponsive" 
                    aria-controls="navbarResponsive" 
                    aria-expanded="false" 
                    aria-label="Toggle navigation"
                    onClick={(event)=> {
                    }}>
                        Menu
                    <i className="fa fa-bars ms-1 navbar-toggler" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </button>
                    <div className={ toggle === true ? "collapse navbar-collapse mt-2 id=navbarResponsive" : d-flex }>
                        <ul className="navbar-nav text-uppercase ms-auto py-4 py-lg-0">
                            {navbarData.map((link,idx) => {

                                return (
                                    <li key={link.id} className="nav-item" data-index={idx}><a className="nav-link" href={link.ref}>{link.title}</a></li>

                                );
                            })}
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </>
    );
}

export default Navbar;
```

ThemeContext.js

```
import React, { createContext, useState} from "react";
import useTheme from "../hooks/useTheme";

export const ThemeContext = createContext(); 

function ThemeProvider ({children, startingTheme}) {
    const { theme, setTheme } = useTheme(startingTheme);

    return (
        <ThemeContext.Provider value={
            {theme, setTheme}
        }>    
        {children}    
        </ThemeContext.Provider>
    );

}

export { ThemeProvider };
```

ToggleContext.js

```
import React, { createContext} from 'react'
import { useToggle} from "../hooks/useToggle";

export const ToggleContext = createContext();

function ToggleProvider ({children, startingToggle}){
    const {toggle, setToggle} = useToggle(startingToggle);
    
    return (
        <ToggleContext.Provider value ={{toggle, setToggle}}>  
        {children} 
        </ToggleContext.Provider>
    );
}

export { ToggleProvider }
```

UseTheme.js

```
import { useState } from "react";

function useTheme (startingTheme ="light") {

    const [theme, setTheme] = useState(startingTheme);

    function validateTheme (themeValue) {
        if (themeValue === "dark") {
            setTheme("dark");
        } else {
            setTheme("light");
        }
    }    

    return {
        theme,
        setTheme: validateTheme,
    }
}

export default useTheme;
```

UseToogle.js

```
import { useState } from "react";

function useToggle (startingToggle) {
    const [toggle, setToggle] = useState(startingTheme);

    return {
        toggle,
        setToggle
    }
}

export default useToggle;
```

Layout.js

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import { ThemeContext, ThemeProvider } from "../contexts/ThemeContext";
import { ToggleContext, ToggleProvider} from "../contexts/ToggleContext";
function Layout ({startingTheme, startingToggle, children}) { 
    
    
    return (
        <>
        <ThemeProvider startingTheme={startingTheme}>
            <LayoutNoThemeProvider >{children}</LayoutNoThemeProvider>
        </ThemeProvider>
        <ToggleProvider startingToggle={startingToggle} >
            <LayoutNoToggleProvider>{children}</LayoutNoToggleProvider>
        </ToggleProvider>

        </>
        
    );
}

function LayoutNoToggleProvider ({children}) {
    
    const { toggle } = useContext(ToggleContext);
    return (
        <div className={
            toggle === false ? "d-none" : "d-flex"
        }>
        {children}
        </div>
    )
}


function LayoutNoThemeProvider ({ children }) {
    const { theme } = useContext(ThemeContext);

    return (
        <>
        <div className={
            theme === "light" ? "container-fluid bg-white" : "container-fluid bg-dark"
        }>
        {children}
        </div>
        </>
    
    );
}
export default Layout;
```

Navbar

```
import Image from "next/image";
import styles from "../../styles/Home.module.scss"
import Logo  from "../../public/Knowledge Memo.svg"
import { useContext } from "react";
import { ThemeContext } from "../contexts/ThemeContext";
import { ToggleContext } from "../contexts/ToggleContext";

const navbarData  = [
    {   id: "1",
        title: "home",
        ref: "#home"
    },
    {   id:"2",
        title: "Skills",
        ref: "#skills"
    },
    {   id:"3",
        title: "The List",
        ref: "#theList"
    },
    {   id: "4",
        title: "Team",
        ref: "#team"
    },
    {   id: "5",
        title: "Contact",
        ref: "#contact"
    },
];

function Navbar() {

    const {theme} = useContext(ThemeContext);
    const {toggle} = useContext(ToggleContext);

    return (
        <>
            <nav className={
                theme === "light" ? 
                "navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark fixed-top": 
                "navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top id= mainNav"}>
                <div className="container d-flex flex justify-content-between">
                    <a className="navbar-brand h-50" href="#page-top">
                    <div className="navbar-brand"> 
                    <Image 
                    src={Logo} 
                    alt="..."                  
                    fill="#fff"
                    objectFit="contain"
                    className="h-50"                    
                    />
                    </div>
                    </a>                    
                    <button 
                    className="navbar-toggler collapsed" 
                    type="button" 
                    data-bs-toggle="collapse" 
                    data-bs-target="#navbarResponsive" 
                    aria-controls="navbarResponsive" 
                    aria-expanded="false" 
                    aria-label="Toggle navigation"
                    onClick={(event)=> {
                    }}>
                        Menu
                    <i className="fa fa-bars ms-1 navbar-toggler" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </button>
                    <div className={ toggle === true ? "collapse navbar-collapse mt-2 id=navbarResponsive" : d-flex }>
                        <ul className="navbar-nav text-uppercase ms-auto py-4 py-lg-0">
                            {navbarData.map((link,idx) => {

                                return (
                                    <li key={link.id} className="nav-item" data-index={idx}><a className="nav-link" href={link.ref}>{link.title}</a></li>

                                );
                            })}
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </>
    );
}

export default Navbar;
```

Is it possible for someone to point out what i did wrong? please?

Many thanks,

Leo

Comment: I can see that your issue is that you've imported your toggle incorrectly with ````````import { useToggle} from "../hooks/useToggle";````````, however what I don't understand is how that doesn't just break your code immediately and how using ````useToggle(startingToggle);```` later on even works.  I'd have thought destructing a non existing value would just error, but someone it seems it works with importing modules.  Perhaps it's destructuring the actual function inside that module, I dunno.

Comment: Hi @Matriarx, thanks for pointing this out, i have amended it but it seems the error is still coming up. I can make my head around it....